# how to implement autocomplete combobox in tornadofx

Tags: tornadofx

I have gone through the doc but no luck. Where as there is autocomplete in the github repo. Please provide a working example of tornadofx auto complete combobox?

Answer (score 2):

In it's simplest form, you just call `makeAutocompletable()` on a ComboBox. Here is a complete view with a Form.

```
class MyView : View() {
    val selectedFruit = SimpleStringProperty()
    val fruits = listOf("Apple", "Banana", "Pear")

    override val root = form {
        fieldset {
            field("Fruit") {
                combobox(selectedFruit, fruits) {
                    makeAutocompletable()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do i need this "selectedFruit" in combobox ()?

Comment: how to resize the suggestion list width ?